# Не работает yandex коллекция (неизвестная ошибка) yandex_share

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день,

Подскажите почему не работает yandex коллекция. При нажатии Добавить выводит : неизвестная ошибка.
Пример ссылки: http://online.zakon.kz/Document/?doc_id=33488654

А  в Google+ не подставляет image, хотя og:image задан и в другие соц сети он передается.

Comment: по поводу Гугл - там проставляются другие параметры мета: 
<meta itemprop="image" content="https://website.com/image250X250.png"/> - здесь описание http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?id=1959 .

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку, ваша ссылка к сожалению не рабочая. Нашел подобное на https://uguide.ru/kak-podkljuchit-knopki-socialnykh-setej-dlja-sajta но все равно Google+ отказывается ставить мою картинку :(

А по поводу Yandex коллекции есть какие либо предложения ?

Comment: @DonaldTramp Сейчас проблема воспроизводится? В каком браузере проверяете?

Comment: @РоманПарадеев, К сожалению это не зависит от браузера. Проверяю в Google Chrome и Mozilla Firefox. Можете зайти по ссылке выше или открыть любой другой документ и попробовать. Мне само интересно почему коллекция от яндекса ломается на самом себе.

Comment: Увидел. Разберёмся, спасибо!

Comment: @РоманПарадеев наверное вы уже заметили что конструктор index.bundle.js и vendor.bundle.js ломается после того как удалишь картинку. А ошибка возникает при POST передачи данных Яндексу. Уже начал грешить на MIXED Content при открытой странице через HTTP протокол, но через HTTPS тоже самое. Это вам спасибо за поддержку!

Comment: Проблему решил. На сайте путь до статического контента сделан без протокола. По этому если указываете путь до картинок необходимо указывать его с протоколом.